# Django, how to have an array in model without M2M?

Tags: sql, django, django-models, relational-database, m2m

I want my model to have an array of other model's instances. Let me explain.

I have a `Company` model which has a `localizations` field which is supposed to be a set/array of addresses. Since one address can only be for one `Company`, M2M relationship seems wrong here.

When `Company` gets deleted, all of its `localizations` should also be deleted.

How do I accomplish that? (I don't use Postgres)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation you want a `ForeignKey` (which is a many-to-one relationship). See the code below:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    ...

class Address(models.Model):
     company = models.ForeignKey(Comapny, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="localizations")
     address_line_1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
     # Other fields you want
     ...
```

Each `Address` points to one `Company` instance. But there is no limit on how many `Address`s can point to a `Company`. In this sense, a company "has" many addresses.

The `related_name="localizations"` argument, means that you can do `company.localizations` to get an array of the `Address` instances that point to that company.

Finally, `on_delete=models.CASCADE` means that if you delete a `Company` instance, the `Address` instances that point to it will also be deleted.

Comment: Is it efficient? Everytime when I wanna get some company's addresses I need to query through companies.

Comment: Yes, this will be at least as efficient as any other method you could use.